# How do you launch a Casperjs script from Python

Tags: python, casperjs

Using Subprocess is not working.   In the command prompt I would run the Casperjs file like this.

```
casperjs.bat test.js
```

Subprocess if failing on me as the script is not an exe.   Unfortunately I'm working within the Windows environment.

```
cmd = ['/projects/casperjs/batchbin/casperjs.bat',  '/projects/music/test.js']
        response = subprocess.check_output(cmd, 
                shell=False,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

*Error returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: I tried shell=True as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is really two part.   The only way to do this since Python knows nothing about JavaScript is to use subprocess to pre-pend the parameter pointing towards phantomjs then your script.  Within your script you will need to point towards the Casper.batch file.   This is documented in their how-to.   Using subprocess you can capture the output from the command line.

```
    APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    PHANTOM = '/projects/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe'
    SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'iTunesScriptSingle.js')
    params = [PHANTOM, SCRIPT, song, artist]
    child = subprocess.Popen(params, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        out = child.stderr.read(1)
        return out
        if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
            break
        if out != '':
            sys.stdout.write(out)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            return out
```

Comment: This answer from Chris is cool. You can also check out http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py

Comment: My IDE says: `if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
            break` is unreachable